# Frozen Logon after fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Dell Latitude 7490

Tags: login, 22.04, dell

I need help with ubuntu installation on my laptop Dell Latitude 7490 I need to get rid of frozen logon after the End of installation. (the installation is done correctly but ubuntu gets stuck on the login screen and sometimes on the desktop after a few seconds)
I don't know the origin of the issue (graphics or CPU).

PS: the same problem with Garuda Dragonized but in this case, it freezes when the live USB starts booting the system!

Comment: DId you do a fresh install from a USB, and which formats the entire hard drive, or installs to a partition?

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply didn't notice the comment section,
yes the installation is from live USB (the hard drive is nvme and without partition a fresh install).

Comment: I would try re-creating the live USB from scratch (or even get one from amazon/ebay), reformat during the install and try again. It can have some random fault and the best thing to do is just re-try. Could be some error in the live USB or during the installation. Just re-try from the beginning. If that doesn't work, try perhaps a USB with a slightly older version of Ubuntu and see if that works?

Comment: found a way this problem is related to the GPU (UHD 620 Intel Graphics) 
by just adding this to the terminal after choosing safe mode without graphics:

sudo echo "options i915 enable_psr=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with more recent kernels is to disable the PSR feature, by creating this configuration file:

```
sudo echo "options i915 enable_psr=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these kernel parameters may solve the problem

```
acpi_enforce_resources=lax i915.enable_psr=0
```

That can be achieved by:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. Modify `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, append the parameters to the line

Reference : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255162

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit this issue after installing Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 7490 laptop and updated everything (kernel 5.19.0-41-generic now). I first tried with `options i915 enable_psr=0` in `/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf`, but that only delayed the freeze. Then adding also `enable_dc=0` seems to make the system stable, so the full line in `/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf` that works for me is `options i915 enable_psr=0 enable_dc=0`.